# SVGO custom plugin. How to store attr().value before removeAttr

Tags: javascript, svg, npm, foreach

I'm trying to build a custom plugin for SVGO, to batch clean and format svg exported from illustrator.

This part aims is to keep same aspects elements into groups with class instead of having classes on each elements.

Things are working quite fine, except when I try to remove classes of elements, the loop looses track of it, and I can't figure out why ?

If anyone could help, it would be really cool !

Here is the excerpt from my code:

```js
//before it, loop through elements with conditions to keep <g></g> as "g"
var myclass;
g.content.forEach(function(inner){
  if (inner.hasAttr("class")){
    myclass = inner.attr('class').value; // this works as expected
    inner.removeAttr('class'); // this mess it all although it is called after (myclass = "")
    }
});

g.addAttr({
  name: 'class',
  value: myclass,
  prefix: '',
  local: ''
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`class` attr is a `CSSClassList`, so it's not supposed to remove I guess. That was added not so long ago (v1.0 or so) to deal with styles better (for plugins like `inlineStyles` and `minifyStyles`). Looking at `lib/svgo/css-class-list.js`, I think something like `inner.attr('class').setClassValue()` (with empty or `undefined` parameter value) should remove all classes. Haven't tested though.

Comment: Also, corresponding methods should be used for adding class like
`g.attr('class').setClassValue(myclass)`

Comment: Hello Lev, thank you for your answers, but I cannot manage to make it work. I have this message: `setClassValue is not a function`. I tried to require `object.values` or `CSSClassList` without success, do I miss something ?

Comment: Then I don't know, what version do you use, and what problem do you have.